# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cats/FlatMapArityFunctions when using circe and cats libraries

Tags: scala, dependencies, classpath, scala-cats, circe

I'm encountering a runtime error when using the **`circe`** and **`cats`** libraries together in my Scala code. The error message I receive is **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cats/FlatMapArityFunctions`**. I would appreciate any insights into this issue.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
sealed trait SuperJob {

  def name: String

}

object SuperJob {

  implicit val encodeJob: Encoder[SuperJob] = Encoder.instance {
    case job @ FirstSuperJob(_)  => job.asJson
    case job @ SecondSuperJob(_) => job.asJson
  }

  implicit val decodeJob: Decoder[SuperJob] = List[Decoder[SuperJob]](
    Decoder[FirstSuperJob].widen,
    Decoder[SecondSuperJob].widen
  ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
}

case class FirstSuperJob(name: String) extends SuperJob

object FirstSuperJob {

  implicit def decoder: Decoder[FirstSuperJob] = deriveDecoder
  implicit def encoder: Encoder[FirstSuperJob] = deriveEncoder

}

case class SecondSuperJob(name: String) extends SuperJob

object SecondSuperJob {

  implicit def decoder: Decoder[SecondSuperJob] = deriveDecoder
  implicit def encoder: Encoder[SecondSuperJob] = deriveEncoder

}

object example extends App {
  val firstJob  = FirstSuperJob("firstjob")
  val secondJob = SecondSuperJob("secondjob")

  println(firstJob.name)
  println(secondJob.name)

  val firstJson = FirstSuperJob.encoder(firstJob)
  println(firstJson)

  val secondJson = SecondSuperJob.encoder(secondJob)
  println(secondJson)

  // Run time error below!!!!
  try {
    val firstDecodeResult = firstJson.as[FirstSuperJob]

    println(firstDecodeResult)

  } catch {
    case ex: Throwable => println(s"caught exception: ${ex}")
  }
}
```

I have the following dependency in my build.sbt:

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
firstjob
secondjob
{
  "name" : "firstjob"
}
{
  "name" : "secondjob"
}
caught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cats/FlatMapArityFunctions
```

I am expecting this instead:

```
firstjob
secondjob
{
  "name" : "firstjob"
}
{
  "name" : "secondjob"
}
Right(FirstSuperJob(firstjob))
```

I have following dependencies in my build.sbt

```
val catsVersion = "2.2.0"
val circeVersion = "0.13.0"

"io.circe"        %% "circe-core"    % circeVersion,
"io.circe"        %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
"io.circe"        %% "circe-parser"  % circeVersion,
"io.circe"        %% "circe-literal" % circeVersion,
"org.typelevel"   %% "cats-core"     % catsVersion,
"org.typelevel"   %% "cats-effect"   % catsVersion
```

I have tried searching for a solution but haven't been able to find one that resolves this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How are you running the code? Did you package it? Have you tried `sbt dependencyTree` to find out conflicts in libraries ?

Comment: 1. Don't use the same version for **cats-core** and **cats-effect** - 2. You probably want to use **CE3**. - 3. Try upgrading everything _(including your **Scala** and **sbt**)_ to their latest versions _(for **Scala** just the latest patch)_.

Comment: NCDFE is a linking error that indicates the jars you compiled against aren't matching what you run against. Update to the latest versions as Luis suggests and double check `sbt evicted`.

Comment: Resolved this by analysing dependencyTree. http4s was bringing in unwanted cats-effect version and this error disappeared by excluding it while importing http4s lib. Thanks everyone!

Comment: That's not a safe solution, you need to use the correct version of http4s and cats-effect together or you'll get *other* linking errors. Update your cats-effect, 2.x series is ancient

Comment: @Daenyth Yeah you are right, I have updated cats-core to 2.9 series and removed exclude from http4s, which also resolved this issue. I'll be updating cats-effect now but I guess I'll have to upgrade a few things in my code supported by newer version of cats-effect. Thanks btw!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's caused by a build misconfiguration that's now resolved